# Bad use of LaTeX3 error messages

Tags: latex3, error-writing

What is my error in the code below? It gives :

```
Missing \endcsname inserted.
<to be read again> 
                   \cs_set_nopar:Npx 
l.34 \begin{bdoclatex}[KO]
```

Code used.

```
\documentclass{article}

\RequirePackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{minted}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\msg_set:nnnn { bdoc } { bdoclatex-unknown-formating }
    { Unknown ~ options ~ for ~ the ~ environment ~ bdoclatex. }
    { You ~ can ~ use ~ sbs (side-by-side), ~ code ~ or ~ std (standard). }

\NewDocumentCommand{\formatting}{m}{
    \str_case:nnF { #1 } {
        {sbs}{listing ~ side ~ text}
        {code}{listing ~ only}
        {std}{listing ~ and ~ text } % What to add here ?
    } {
        \msg_error:nn { bdoc } { bdoclatex-unknown-formating }
    }
}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\newtcblisting{bdoclatex}[1][std]{%
    \formatting{#1}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{bdoclatex}[sbs]
    $A = B + C$
\end{bdoclatex}

\begin{bdoclatex}[KO]
    $A = B + C$
\end{bdoclatex}

\end{document}
```

Comment: For your approach to work you'd need `\formatting` to be fully expandable, you can achieve this by using `\NewExpandableDocumentCommand` and `\msg_expandable_error:nn` instead, but the expandable error messages are very limitted and don't show the useful information for your message (`! Package bdoc Error: Unknown options for the environment b...`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're using the wrong tool.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{minted}

\tcbset{
  sbs/.style=listing side text,
  code/.style=listing only,
  std/.style=listing and text,
}

\newtcblisting{bdoclatex}[1][std]{#1}

\begin{document}

\begin{bdoclatex}[sbs]
    $A = B + C$
\end{bdoclatex}

\begin{bdoclatex}[code]
    $A = B + C$
\end{bdoclatex}

\begin{bdoclatex}[std]
    $A = B + C$
\end{bdoclatex}

\begin{bdoclatex}
    $A = B + C$
\end{bdoclatex}

\begin{bdoclatex}[KO]
    $A = B + C$
\end{bdoclatex}

\end{document}
```

With the last one you get the standard

```
! Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/tcb/KO' and I am going to 
ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it.
```

Comment: Really cleaner code... Thanks. But is it still possible to emit an error? Sorry for my curiosity. ;-)

Comment: @projetmbc Error management of pgfkeys doesn't seem very flexible.

Comment: OK, I will accept it. :-)

Comment: @projetmbc You could install a custom unknown-key-handler that throws your message (but that would apply to every unknown key in the `/tcb`-path).